# Can't make jQuery dynamic selector work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on what seems to be a simple script, making buttons toggle divs in and out of view. I've done so before, but this time I'm using dynamic selectors in jQuery, and can't see what is wrong.

If I make the call a static one (ie: '#liste_21'), it works like a charm, but as the number of item is not now in advance, I would prefer to get the dynamic version working.

Any idea what's wrong?

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".jour").click(function() {
            var jour = $(this).text();
            $('#liste_'+jour).slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="calendrierActivites">
    <div id="nov20" class="jour">
        <span>20</span>
    </div>
    <div id="nov21" class="jour">
        <span>21</span>
    </div>
    <div id="nov22" class="jour">
        <span>22</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="liste_20">
    <h2>20 novembre</h2>
</div>
<div id="liste_21">
    <h2>21 novembre</h2>
</div>

<div id="liste_22">
    <h2>22 novembre</h2>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5yqsptry/#

Comment: `$(this).text()` => prints the extra whitespaces try to `trim()` it : `$(this).text().trim()`

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yqsptry/2/)

```
var jour = $(this).find('span').text();
```

`$(this).text()` will get the text inside the `div` with class of `jour` and you're using the wrong selector.

Comment: Any idea why the span add white space characters?  The suggestion by @four of trimming the string also worked, so I'm wondering what exactly was added.

Comment: Within each `.jour` div, you have line breaks and tabs, potentially spaces around the `<span>` element too. There isn't any of that inside your span, thus making it a bit safer to grab from!

Comment: its not the span... `.text()` actually gets all descendant text of the parent element including the line terminators and whitespaces towards the end of that element. This is why its safer to select the 'span' element and get its text value

Answer (score 2):

jQuery docs on [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) say that

> Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.

You can simply trim out the whitespace:

```
var jour = $(this).text().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the jour value

fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/5yqsptry/3/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".jour").click(function() {

        var jour = $(this).text();

        $('#liste_'+$.trim(jour)).slideToggle();
    });
});
```